# How do I replicate Django Admin-like CRUD for related objects?

Tags: django

I was able to add a PLUS button to a select widget in a CreateView like in Django Admin. I would like to add objects to the related model using the related model's CreateView by opening a new window using the PLUS button in the CreateView of the child model. After saving the related object, I should be able to go back to the previous CreateView to finish my entry. Any tutorials or guides on how to this like in Django Admin?

Comment: Search for django admin inlines

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed I have tried inlines but I have only used it in formsets, I am referring to opening a separate CreateView of the related model then returning to the previous model with the updated related object.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects